# ant sshexec terminating without giving any message

Tags: ant

I am trying to unzip a zip file which is available in the remote server. 
After completing there is a log entry and this is not coming at all. 
output file also don't have much details.

1.) how can I disable sshexec console print?
2.) Why this is not printing final logger statement? 
3.) Is this not extracting full zip file?

```
<target name="unzip">
    <echo level="info">==== Extracting zip file ====</echo>
        <sshexec host="${host}" username="${user}" password="${password}" output="${log.file}" command="unzip -o  ${path}/${zipdata}.zip -d ${path2}/${zipdata}/" trust="true" />
    <echo level="info">==== Extracting zip file completed====</echo>
</target>
```

Comment: You should try running commands manually.